# openAI query is working when prompt is "hi" but don't work for any other prompt

Tags: flutter, openai-api

I am using chat_gpt_sdk plugin for openai and it is working correctly if I give prompt with "hi" otherwise it does not work.

I have also checked, my tokens are still remaining and credit is also there.

```
final request = ChatCompleteText(
      model: GptTurbo0301ChatModel(),
      messages: _messagesHistory,
      maxToken: 2000,
      
    );
    try {
      final response = await _openAI.onChatCompletion(request: request);
      for (var element in response!.choices) {
        if (element.message != null) {
          setState(() {
            _messages.insert(
              0,
              ChatMessage(
                  user: _gptChatUser,
                  createdAt: DateTime.now(),
                  text: element.message!.content),
            );
          });
        }
      }
    } on OpenAIRateLimitError catch (err) {
      log.e('catch OpenAIRateLimitError ->${err.data?.error?.toMap()}');
    } on OpenAIServerError catch (err) {
      UtilityFunctions.createToast(
          context, "You have exceeded the limit.\nPlease try again later.");
      log.e('catch OpenAIServerError ->${err.data?.error?.toMap()}');
    } catch (e) {
      log.e(e);
    }
```

[image: Error and propmt screenshot]